# Storing multiple strings In C

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

How can multiple strings be stored in C?
if we consider that the number of strings are taken from user , how can we save them in c language , considering that we had not declared any char strings before asking the number of strings from user , because the number of strings was not available.here is what i did but i ended up printing the first character of strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
char array[a][1];
for(int i = 0 ; i < a ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 1 ; j++)
    {
    scanf("%s",&array[i][j]);
    }
}
    for(int i = 0 ; i < a ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 1 ; j++)
    {
    printf("%c",array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a rule of thumb, when you are trying to do something new with strings, it behooves you to first see if you know how to do it with `int`. Do you know how to store a variable number of `int`?

Comment: @Beta thanks dude ! yes I'm familiar with basic concepts of both storing a variable of char and a variable of int.

Comment: Allocate a buffer.  Read the input.  Repeat.

Comment: A variable **number** of `int`, good. And you know how to construct a string: you wind up with a pointer to the first element of an array of `char`. So can you store a variable number of such pointers?

Comment: You need an array of char for every string. You need an array of char* to store all the strings. Do you know how to allocate and deallocate memory with `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: @Amin "storing a variable of char and a variable of int" Do you mean you understand how array of `char` or `int` are stored?   In that case, to store multiple **string** ( which is  array of `char`s) you'll need to create another iteration of **array**  i.e.  **array** of **array** of `char`s .    Also, its considered a good practice at SO to show your effort at solving the problem.

Comment: @beta yes , I can store a variable number of such pointer.

Comment: @BugSquasher I agree with your opinion .unfortunately , not familiar with them !

Comment: @vvy do you mean it requires multidimensional array of char? if so , I tried to do so , but when printing the strings , i ended up printing only the first character of the string.

Comment: If you tried something that almost work, edit your question and add the code you already wrote and tell us what it doesn't work as you expect. Then we can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning.
I don't think you really understand what is **char** though. Char is only ONE character. So things like `char array[16][1]` mean that you have array of 16 strings where each string have maximum length of one. Also your next step `scanf("%s", &array[i][j]);` doesn't make sense, since you're getting multiple symbols as an input, but you're writing only to single character. Proper solution would be something like this:

```
char array[a][255]; // 255 will be maximum length of one 'string'
for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
    scanf("%s", array[i]);
}
```

As you can see, you don't need **&** sign here, because *array[i]* already returns address of the first character in the string. The same thing applies to printing. Proper way is to do following thing:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
}
```

Your solution only displays one character.
And remember, **char** is just basic number, ranging typically from 0-255 (if compiler defaults **char** to **unsigned char**). Your code implies that you treat char as a full C++ string, which it definitely isn't.